# QGIS grid SRS latitude longitude problem

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mapping, grids-graticules

I'm having an issue on my beginners GIS course. I'm having a problem with the grid when I try and create a map on QGIS. The SRS appears to be fine everywhere until it comes to displaying the grid. I want the grid in degrees for latitude and longitude but I'm just not able to do that and I can't see why. Everything seems to be set up okay and the datasets are positioned in the correct place.
Any advice?  Please bear in mind I am totally new to this so may need a fair bit of guiding here.  No one on my course has been able to help so far.

Full details and screenshots are here:  https://community.verdantlearn.org/t/module-4-grid-help/893/4

Comment: Click on 'Change' next to CRS to open the Coordinate Reference System Selector dialog and select WGS84 EPSG:4326. You can filter to it quickly by typing '4326' into the filter bar. Then change the interval values to 0.05 or 0.075 as per the instructions. Also have a look at: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/making_a_map.html

Comment: Thank you!  That's worked perfectly!  I really appreciate your help.  I can look forward to learning more now :)  Thank you :)

Comment: Great! No problem :)

Comment: @ BenW since you solved it in a comment, perhaps upgrade this to an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: Please avoid statements of urgency in questions. They can result in downvotes and answer aversion.